# Java webapp. Sell modules

Tags: java, module

Hi guys im starting to create a webapp in java, its a erp, i want to create separated modules like, sells (possible operations here) and buys for the main project, but i want to sell it like a core with some other modules availabe i want to add GPS for delivery bikes for example or a chat module, but my problem its how to develop it.
i need to create all modules on the same project? or sell just the core?
if i sell just the core. How can add a specific module later?

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/HowOSGi)? It is a framework for building modular applications. Eclipse is based on it and it's pretty great. There are lots of other options as well.

It seems you are pretty early in your project, so I would recommend working towards a minimum viable product (or even prototype) with the understanding and express intent that this code will be thrown away. Once that is working, you can get more specific guidance on how to architect the final product.

Comment: Thanks but not usefull i just want to create a core and add functionalities

Comment: Those are very vague requirements - working off of an MVP or OSGi will make things much easier. If all you want to do is create a core and add stuff, why not just make a maven project for the core and include this in other projects as required? There's a lot of engineering effort in making truly pluggable systems and I'd recommend starting with a prototype. It's easier to modularize something that works than to come up with an ideal architecture out of thin air.

Comment: i will work with MVC with JSF. I will create a Usefull core for X amount of money and later add another module for Y money. but my problem its how to add the module to the main core or if i must develop and use specific rules like users privileges to activate the modules.

Comment: If you want to accomplish that, you need to use specific role based authorization on the modules. So, you want to have a modular design (of course, we all want that regardless of whether we charge for modules). If you have no core and no modular or plugin based architecture, how can you do that? I would build your core codebase in a way that attempts to be modular, then evaluate how to expand it later - this is a very program specific question.

Comment: ok. so the best option is use specific role based for you?.
but if i dont want to share my class files while i dont get the money for them? i mean i got a client with just core, but if i use specific role option i need deploy the entire solution, if someone get the rules it can use all the modules without pay right?

Comment: The best option is to cleanly write your code and separate the functionality into separate packages as best you can. Evaluate using OSGi or another plugin mechanism as your code is mature. For selling particular functionality, sure you want a sophisticated and secure role based authorization and authentication system. All of this is a lot of work, but if you start with a prototype and cleanly refactor and test it a few times, you can do it.

Comment: That's why I suggested OSGi - it's the plugin mechanism that eclipse is built on and it supports adding code dynamically at runtime. You can see people selling modular code with OSGi every day - I used to work at a company that did this.

Comment: osgi is ok for webapp?

Comment: Sure thing, I've done it before - OSGi is just the code for managing plugins and loading them at runtime. This is not the best article but it's even in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/osgi.htm#GSDVG00488)

Comment: know some git to test it?

Comment: This has a full source link in it, check it out https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tutorial:_Building_your_first_OSGi_Remote_Service

Comment: i check it but its not what im looking thanks any way